# How to bind local property on control in WPF

Tags: wpf, binding, properties, local

I have two controls on WPF

```
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        Name="btnChange"
        Click="btnChange_Click"
        Content="Click Me" />

<Label Name="lblCompanyId"
       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
       DataContext="{Binding ElementName=_this}"
       Content="{Binding Path=CompanyName}" />
```

As we can see that label is bound to local property(in code Behind), I don't see any value on label when I click button...

Below is my code behind...

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty CompanyNameProperty =
  DependencyProperty.Register("CompanyName", typeof(string), typeof(Window3), new UIPropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

public string CompanyName {
  get { return (string)this.GetValue(CompanyNameProperty); }
  set { this.SetValue(CompanyNameProperty, value); }
}

private void btnChange_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
  this.CompanyName = "This is new company from code beind";
}
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try:

```
Content="{Binding ElementName=_this, Path=CompanyName}"
```

Without the `DataContext` binding.

**EDIT**

I have no problems with your code, have named your window to `x:Name="_this"`?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfStackOverflowSpielWiese.Window3"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window3"
        Height="300"
        Width="300"
        x:Name="_this">
  <Grid>
    <StackPanel>
      <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              Name="btnChange"
              Click="btnChange_Click"
              Content="Click Me" />

      <Label Name="lblCompanyId"
             HorizontalAlignment="Center"
             DataContext="{Binding ElementName=_this}"
             Content="{Binding Path=CompanyName}"></Label>

    </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Is your window really `Window3`?

```
public partial class Window3 : Window
{
  public Window3() {
    this.InitializeComponent();
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty CompanyNameProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("CompanyName", typeof(string), typeof(Window3), new UIPropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

  public string CompanyName {
    get { return (string)this.GetValue(CompanyNameProperty); }
    set { this.SetValue(CompanyNameProperty, value); }
  }

  private void btnChange_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    this.CompanyName = "This is new company from code behind";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks punker76. Your solution worked! I had just needed to add x:Name="_this" and boooom.

Comment: Fast forward to 2021, and if you try doing this, you get the following error: `MyView.xaml(15,3): error MC3054: The type 'MyView' cannot have a Name attribute. Value types and types without a default constructor can be used as items within a ResourceDictionary.` - What is the solution then?

Answer (score 9):

You are currently binding your Label's `DataContext` to a `Button`, and then trying to set it's `Content` to `CompanyName`, however `CompanyName` is not a valid property on `Button`

Specify `DataContext` in your binding `Path` to bind to `Button.DataContext.CompanyName` instead of `Button.CompanyName`

Also, I'd recommend just binding the Content instead of binding both the DataContext and Content

```
<Label Content="{Binding ElementName=btnChange, Path=DataContext.CompanyName}" />
```

And if your code looks exactly like the code sample posted, then both the `Button` and `Label` have the same `DataContext`, so you can bind directly to `CompanyName`

```
<Label Content="{Binding CompanyName}" />
```

**Edit**

Just noticed that your Label's binding was to a control named `_this`. I had assumed it was the Button, although I see now that your Button's name is `btnChange`, not `_this`.

It doesn't matter though, the answer is still the same. You're trying to bind to a UI Control's `CompanyName` property, which is not a valid property.

Comment: @punker76 See my edit. `_this` has to refer to some UI control, and I mistakenly assumed it referred to the Button since it was part of the code sample. The principal still applies, even if it the control isn't a Button.

Comment: Adding the ElementName in the Binding...just what I've been looking for all afternoon!  Thanks!